# Differences between assignment constructor and others in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment, shared-ptr

Consider:

*`std::shared_ptr<Res> ptr=new Res();`*

The above statement doesn't work. The compiler complains there isn't any viable conversion....

While the below works

*`std::shared_ptr<Res> ptr{new Res()} ;`*

How is it possible?!

Actually, what are the main differences in the constructor{uniform, parentheses, assignments}?

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: What is meant by "uniform" in the second (last) question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think some people say uniform initializer to {}

Comment: @Mehran: Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: @PeterMortensen the first type that i used it in the question is its example.  People call it list initialization, braces initialization, and uniform initialization. If you search "uniform initialization" you will see this term is widely used.

Comment: OK, *[Uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization)* (includes an example)

Comment: @Mehran: I don't know why they would downvote. I can only guess: The question is incomplete (for example, the actual compiler error is missing), the last question is partly incomprehensible (I am not saying it is; it may not be to some), the question ***looks*** like it has been asked a thousand times before (because it is so short), etc. It could be for any number of reasons. This is only speculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247571/discussion-between-mehran-and-peter-mortensen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `std::shared_ptr` taking a raw pointer is marked as `explicit`; that's why `=` does not allow you to invoke this constructor.

Using `std::shared_ptr<Res> ptr{new Res()};` is syntax that allows you to call the an explicit constructor to initialize the variable.

```
std::shared_ptr<Res> ptr=new Res();
```

would invoke an implicit constructor taking a pointer to `Res` as single parameter, but not an explicit one.

Here's a simplified example using a custom class with no assignment operators and just a single constructor:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int i) { }

    // mark all automatically generated constructors and assignment operators as deleted
    Test(Test&&) = delete;
    Test& operator=(Test&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    Test t = 1;
}
```

Now change the constructor to

```
explicit Test(int i) { }
```

and the `main` function will no longer compile; the following alternatives would still be viable:

```
Test t(1);
Test t2{1};
```

Comment: oh, i didn't know marking constructor as explicit requires calling it without assignment! is there any reason that the implementation marks this constructor as explicit?!

Comment: @Mehran this makes it harder to accidentally assign ownership. If you've got a type that could be converted to a pointer implicitly, this otherwise could easily result in an issue, e.g. `int foo[3]; std::shared_ptr<int> bar = foo;`; that's why you need to be explicit...